# Exception while using lateral view in Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, brickhouse

I am using the below code to parse xml data in Hive.  In my xml data, a few tags are repeating so I am using the brickhouse jar and lateral view to parse the tags and place in Hive tables.  But when I am executing my code, I am getting an error. Please help as I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

**Code:**

```
add jar /home/cloudera/brickhouse-0.5.5.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION numeric_range AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.NumericRange';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION array_index AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayIndexUDF';
add jar /home/cloudera/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS medinfo2;
create table medinfo2 as
select array_index(statusCode,n) AS statusCode,
    array_index(startTime,n) AS startTime,
    array_index(endTime,n) AS endTime,
    array_index(strengthValue,n) AS strengthValue,
    array_index(strengthUnits,n) AS strengthUnits
from medications_info7 lateral view numeric_range(size( statusCode )) n1 as n;
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
>           at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>           at com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.objectinspector.XmlListObjectInspector.getListElement(XmlListObjectInspector.java:79)
>           at brickhouse.udf.collect.ArrayIndexUDF.evaluate(ArrayIndexUDF.java:59)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:186)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluatorHead._evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluatorHead.java:44)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:77)
>           ... 25 more
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
>       MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>       Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>       Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

**Sample:**

```
<document>
 <code>10160-0</code>
 <entryInfo> 
    <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
    <startTime>20110729</startTime>
    <endTime>20110822</endTime>
    <strengthValue>24</strengthValue>
    <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
 </entryInfo> 
 <entryInfo>
    <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
    <startTime>20120130</startTime>
    <endTime>20120326</endTime>
    <strengthValue>12</strengthValue>
    <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
 </entryInfo>
 <entryInfo>
    <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
    <startTime>20100412</startTime>
    <endTime>20110822</endTime>
    <strengthValue>8</strengthValue>
    <strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits>
 </entryInfo>  
</document>
```

My actual sample is huge in size and contains a lot of these tags which are repeated.

Comment: What does the data in `medications_info7` look like?  Try `numeric_range(size(statusCode) - 1)` instead of `numeric_range(size(statusCode))`

Comment: @GoBrewers14 I want to enter the repeated tags in hive as `struct`. How can i do that . please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your data looks like in Hive because you didn't provide that information so here is how I loaded your XML into Hive.

**Loader**:

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.tbl;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.tbl (
  code STRING,
  entryInfo ARRAY<MAP<STRING,STRING>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.code"="/document/code/text()",
  "column.xpath.entryInfo"="/document/entryInfo/*"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<document>",
  "xmlinput.end"="</document>"
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'someFile.xml' INTO TABLE db.tbl;
```

In the [Hive-XML-SerDe](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources) documentation under section **3 - Arrays**, you can see that they use an array structure to handle repeated tags and in **4 - Maps**, you can see that they use maps to handle entries under a sub-tag.  So, `entryInfo` will be of type `ARRAY<MAP<STRING,STRING>>`.

You can then explode this array, collect like key/vals, and re-combine.

**Query**:

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
ADD JAR /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jars;

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION COLLECT AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

SELECT code
  , m_map['statusCode']    AS status_code
  , m_map['startTime']     AS start_time
  , m_map['endTime']       AS end_time
  , m_map['strengthValue'] AS strength_value
  , m_map['strengthUnits'] AS strength_units
FROM (
  SELECT code
    , COLLECT(m_keys, m_vals) AS m_map
  FROM (
    SELECT code
      , idx
      , MAP_KEYS(entry_info_map)[0]   AS m_keys
      , MAP_VALUES(entry_info_map)[0] AS m_vals
    FROM (
      SELECT code
        , entry_info_map
        , CASE
           WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 0 THEN 0
           WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 1 THEN 1
           WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 2 THEN 2
           ELSE -1
         END AS idx
      FROM db.tbl
      LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(entryInfo) exptbl AS tmp, entry_info_map ) x ) y
  GROUP BY code, idx ) z
```

**Output**:

```
code    status_code     start_time      end_time    strength_value  strength_units
10160-0 completed       20110729        20110822    24              h
10160-0 completed       20120130        20120326    12              h
10160-0 completed       20100412        20110822    8               d
```

Also, you've basically asked this question 4 times ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542958/putting-xml-data-in-hive-struct), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481582/exception-while-using-lateral-view-in-hive), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462410/parse-repeating-xml-tags-in-hive), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446516/parse-repeating-tags-and-store-in-hive)).  This is not a good idea.  Just ask once, edit to add more information, and be patient.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want the data to be in my hive table in column wise format. Please check this for my expected result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462410/parse-repeating-xml-tags-in-hive

Comment: Edited the solution.  You should delete the other three questions that are basically the same as this one.

Comment: Can you please explain me what you are doing in ` WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 0 THEN 0
           WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 1 THEN 1
           WHEN FLOOR(tmp / 5) = 2 THEN 2` as it will be helpfull for me. Also i want to know can i use `entryinfo` in TBLPROPERTIES  as start and end tag ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. please help me in solving this.

Comment: FLOOR(tmp/5) mimics the `divmod()` function.  Try running the query layer by layer and it should be clear what is happening on each level.

Comment: Thanks I'll surely check it. Can you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592863/how-to-set-path-of-particular-xml

Comment: I tried your way it is taking almost 8 minutes to finish even though the file size is 1000kb. Some places values are coming as null. I don't know what is the issue. Can i specify particular path location in my start tag inside tableproperties. e:g `"xmlinput.start"="Document/medicationsInfo/entryInfo",
"xmlinput.end"="</>"`

Comment: If your data is 1000kb, why are you using Hadoop/Hive?

Comment: Right now i am trying for one sample. Going forward my data will be of bigger size and small files with large numbers are going to be there.